# Query prefetched objects without using the db?

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I'm getting multiple objects with prefetched relations from my db:

```
datei_logs = DateiLog.objects.filter(user=request.user)
                             .order_by("-pk")
                             .prefetch_related('transfer_logs')
```

`transfer_logs` refers to this:

```
class TransferLog(models.Model):
  datei_log = models.ForeignKey("DateiLog", related_name="transfer_logs")
  status = models.CharField(
                    max_length=1,
                    choices=LOG_STATUS_CHOICES,
                    default='Good'
                    ) 
  server_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="(no server)")
  server = models.ForeignKey('Server')

  class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Transfer-Logs"

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.server_name
```

Now I want to get all the `TransferLogs` that have a status of `"Good"`. But I think if I do this:

```
datei_logs[0].transfer_logs.filter(...)
```

It queries the db again! Since this happens on a website with many log entries I end up with 900 Queries!

I use:

```
datei_logs[0].transfer_logs.count()
```

As well and it causes lots of queries to the db too!

What can I do to "just get everything" and then just query an object that holds all the information instead of the db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're on Django 1.7 you can use the new [`Prefetch()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) objects to specify the queryset you want to use for the related lookup.

```
queryset = TransferLog.objects.filter(status='Good')
datei_logs = DateiLog.objects.filter(user=request.user)
                             .order_by("-pk")
                             .prefetch_related(Prefetch('transfer_logs', 
                                                        queryset=queryset,
                                                        to_attr='good_logs'))
```

Then you can access `datei_logs[0].good_logs` and check `len(datei_logs[0].good_logs)`.

If you're interested in multiple statuses, you can just use multiple `Prefetch` objects. But if you're going to get all the logs anyway, you might as well stick to your original query and then split the logs up in Python, rather than calling `filter()`.

Comment: but then if i also want bad and neutral logs it means i need one query per Prefetch() per datei_log? this still seems a lot!

Comment: Thank you Kevin! I added your comment to the answer to make it complete.